# How is "Wouldn't have been the pig I would have chosen" related in this joke?

Tags: meaning, jokes

Coach tricked the man to have sex with pig by giving him
a drug:

> Youth 1: How's your man, then, Coach?
>
> Coach: Ah, he'll survive. **Wouldn't have been the pig I would have
>   chosen, though**.

How does "Wouldn't have been the pig I would have chosen" is related to sex joke?

From my English friend, it means "he were the one having sex with the pig he would have chosen a different one". Coach didn't use the word "sex" anywhere, how is it sex joke on pig?

I find these line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on context, it does seem to refer back to the prank.

The "joke" here, though, is that *tricking someone into having sex with a pig in the first place* is **vastly** more... relevant (significant? heinous? unthinkable? horrific?) than the relatively minor detail of *which specific pig they chose* for the "prank".

It's like... remarking on the paint job (or the food service) of a crashed plane. It is beside the point to a ludicrous/absurd degree.